# How to get path of image saved in gallery in android

Tags: android, image, camera

I am making an android application that  takes image from the camera and saves it in the gallery. What i want is to get path of the saved image. I have tried using intent.getData() but is not working..

Comment: will you set display the image into image view?

Comment: Post the code you are using to start the Camera Intent.

Comment: I have already set the image to image view, but i want it it path.because i want to upload it too.

Comment: http://android-spirit.blogspot.in/2013/07/camera-intent-in-android.html

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried using intent.getData() but is not working..

you Will get `intent as NULL` in Some Samsung Devices Like Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android OS Version 4.1.1.

i have face this Problems and Solve it by Below way you can try it out if it helps you.

While Calling intent for Image Capture :

```
String storageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

                    if (storageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                        String filename = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, filename);
                        mImageCaptureUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                values);

                        intent.putExtra(
                                android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                mImageCaptureUri);


                        try {

                            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(BuildInukshk_4_Camera.this)
                                .setMessage(
                                        "External Storeage (SD Card) is required.\n\nCurrent state: "
                                                + storageState)
                                .setCancelable(true).create().show();
                    }

                } else { // pick from file
                    Intent intent = new Intent();

                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                            "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
                }
```

Inside OnActivityResult Method :

```
case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
                Log.i("TAG", "Inside PICK_FROM_CAMERA");

                // Final Code As Below
                try {
                    Log.i("TAG", "inside Samsung Phones");
                    String[] projection = {
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID, // The columns we want
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID,
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND,
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA };
                    String selection = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND + "=" + // Select
                                                                                    // only
                                                                                    // mini's
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND;

                    String sort = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID + " DESC";

                    // At the moment, this is a bit of a hack, as I'm returning ALL
                    // images, and just taking the latest one. There is a better way
                    // to
                    // narrow this down I think with a WHERE clause which is
                    // currently
                    // the selection variable
                    Cursor myCursor = this.managedQuery(
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            projection, selection, null, sort);

                    long imageId = 0l;
                    long thumbnailImageId = 0l;
                    String thumbnailPath = "";

                    try {
                        myCursor.moveToFirst();
                        imageId = myCursor
                                .getLong(myCursor
                                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID));
                        thumbnailImageId = myCursor
                                .getLong(myCursor
                                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID));
                        thumbnailPath = myCursor
                                .getString(myCursor
                                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
                    } finally {
                        // myCursor.close();
                    }

                    // Create new Cursor to obtain the file Path for the large image

                    String[] largeFileProjection = {
                            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA };

                    String largeFileSort = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID
                            + " DESC";
                    myCursor = this.managedQuery(
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            largeFileProjection, null, null, largeFileSort);
                    String largeImagePath = "";

                    try {
                        myCursor.moveToFirst();

                        // This will actually give yo uthe file path location of the
                        // image.
                        largeImagePath = myCursor
                                .getString(myCursor
                                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));
                        mImageCaptureUri_samsung = Uri.fromFile(new File(
                                largeImagePath));
                        mImageCaptureUri = null;
                    } finally {
                        // myCursor.close();
                    }

                    // These are the two URI's you'll be interested in. They give
                    // you a
                    // handle to the actual images
                    Uri uriLargeImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            String.valueOf(imageId));
                    Uri uriThumbnailImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            String.valueOf(thumbnailImageId));

                    // I've left out the remaining code, as all I do is assign the
                    // URI's
                    // to my own objects anyways...
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    mImageCaptureUri_samsung = null;
                    Log.i("TAG",
                            "inside catch Samsung Phones exception " + e.toString());

                }

                try {
                    Log.i("TAG",
                            "URI Samsung:" + mImageCaptureUri_samsung.getPath());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("TAG", "Excfeption inside Samsung URI :" + e.toString());
                }

                try {

                    Log.i("TAG", "URI Normal:" + mImageCaptureUri.getPath());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("TAG", "Excfeption inside Normal URI :" + e.toString());
                }



                break;
```

After Running Below Code you Will get Two URIs `mImageCaptureUri_samsung` and `mImageCaptureUri`

you will get the mImageCaptureUri as your Path if you are running the App with  Simple Devices and you will get your Cpatured Image path in mImageCaptureUri_samsung if you are running with Devices Like Samsung Galaxy S3.

Further you all can go ahead with your Code. it Works For me Very Fine With all the Devices i have tested on.

Also if Someone is having Problem with Above Code than they can reference the Below Great Link [Solution of Samsung Galaxy S3](http://kevinpotgieter.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/null-intent-passed-back-on-samsung-galaxy-tab/)

Hope it will Help.

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
public class Camera extends Activity  {
         private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
         private String selectedImagePath;
         String fileName = "capturedImage.jpg";
         private static Uri mCapturedImageURI; 

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            TakePhoto();
        }

        public void TakePhoto()
        {   
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);  
                mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    values);
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI); 
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }  


        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                {
                  if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) 
                  { 
                    selectedImagePath = getPath(mCapturedImageURI);
                    Log.v("selectedImagePath: ", ""+selectedImagePath);
                     //Save the path to pass between activities
                  }
                }
        }

        public String getPath(Uri uri) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done: 
First create the image uri and with the intent ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE pass an extra MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT with this value.

```
captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            capturedImageURI =  ImageUtils.takePicture(ReceiptFormActivity.this);
                        }
                    });
```

Then onActivityResult convert this uri path to String path and call the method which will fetch the bitmap from this string path and set it on your imageView.

```
                protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == CONSTANTS.TAKE_PICTURE)
            {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {               
                if(capturedImageURI != null)
                {
                    Utils.imagePath = ImageUtils.getStringPathFromURI(ReceiptFormActivity.this, capturedImageURI);;
                    setThumbnail();
                }
            }

        }
    }


    void setThumbnail()
    {
        try{
            if(Utils.imagePath != null)
            {
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.display_image)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        File f = new File(Utils.imagePath);
                        if(f.exists())
                        {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();  
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
                            Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                            intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");  
                            startActivityForResult(intent,2000);
                        }   
                    }
                });

                File imgFilePath = new File(Utils.imagePath);
                if(imgFilePath != null && imgFilePath.exists())
                {
                Bitmap bitmap =  ImageUtils.decodeFile(imgFilePath, CONSTANTS.THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT, CONSTANTS.THUMBNAIL_WIDTH);
                if(bitmap != null)
                {
                receipt_thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                return;
                }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            receipt_thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.some_img);
        }
        /*
         * default img incase of not any exception and no bitmap either.
         */
        receipt_thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.some_img);
    }
```

ImageUtils.java

```
public class ImageUtils {
    public static Uri takePicture(Context context)
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Receipt_" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        Uri mCapturedImageURI = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        Intent intentPicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intentPicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
        ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intentPicture,CONSTANTS.TAKE_PICTURE);

        return mCapturedImageURI;

    }

     public static String getStringPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri)
        {
            try
            {
                String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor =  context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return contentUri.getPath();
            }
        }

         public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f, int thumbnailReqHeight, int thumbnailReqWidth)
        {
            Bitmap b = null;

            try {
                //Decode image size
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);
                fis.close();

                int scale = 1;
                if (o.outHeight > thumbnailReqHeight || o.outWidth > thumbnailReqWidth)
                {
                    scale = (int)Math.pow(2, (int) Math.round(Math.log(thumbnailReqHeight / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
                }

                //Decode with inSampleSize
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                o.inSampleSize = scale;
                fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            return b;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is very fine. Try giving permission of android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in android manifest.